# Apache Camel and JMS cluster (distributed queues)

Tags: jakarta-ee, apache-camel, jms, microservices, messaging

How to use Camel with distributed message queues? Basically I have system of three services, where A is the synchronous boundary to SOAP client. A calls service C, **but gets the result set from service B instead**. Multiple instances of each service is ran to guarantee high availability.

I have to use asynchronous messaging (message queues), because the result to request has to come from different service than called (C can't obtain result set of B, neither A the result set of C, thus services can not be chained synchronically). The biggest challenge is to route response messages to correct instance/thread (A is *synchronous* service, which is blocking until it obtains the result). After doing research, I figured out JMS provides two means for this: *JMSCorrelationID* and *JMSReplyTo* headers. Camel seems to handle these headers transparently.

[image]

But there is even bigger challenge. Of course, I have to run **multiple instances of message queues** also to guarantee high availability. If any message queue goes down, system would be still be available.

**What kind of support Camel provides out-of-the-box for distributed queues?** Let's say I have configured *JMS cluster* in Weblogic, and want to take advantage of it in Camel. What kind of special configuration do I need? Please note, in this example we are using two different queues (or clusters of queues), because Secret result and Result messages can't be meditated on the same queue or server instance, but still the correlation between messages must be preserved all along.

Comment: You have some incredibly complex requirements to fulfill. I'm not sure Camel is what you need here as this sounds like it should be an application rather than an integration. But, if you insist on using Camel, I guess you could utilize [recipientList](http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html) to set the receiving JMS-queue (and broker, I guess) based on some calculations during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try use correlation ID?

Something like this:

```
from("direct:myCall")
.setProperty("myCorrelationId", constant("1"))
.setBody(constant("MESSAGE"))
.to("socket-tcp://SOCKET:16010")
.toD("direct:aggregator")
.end();

from("direct:aggregator")
.aggregate(property("myCorrelationId"),(oldExchange, newExchange) -> {
    if(oldExchange != null) {
        /*do somenthing*/
    }
    if(newExchange != null) {
        /*Do something*/
    }
    return newExchange;
}).eagerCheckCompletion().completionSize(2)
.to("log:foo")
.end();
```

In this example you will have a call with a Correlation ID and an Aggregate route which will wait for 2 messages with the same correlation ID for work using this information.